# The list must filter results as user types in the Input Box

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an Input Box on my Form. When user types in, say, a name of any person, all names that match the entered keywords must appear in a list just below the Input Box. The user must be able to select from the DropDown list and on pressing enter, the DropDown list must disappear.

Is there any JQuery tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ofcouse http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete !